# Module federation remote if available or local alternetive

Tags: dynamic, promise, webpack-module-federation

I have a website with micro services that I load remotely. I want to add an exception handler and load an alternative local component when a given microservice is temporarily down.

E.g. login page:
when the login microservice is enabled, the form will be visible. Otherwise, there should be a message "come back later" in this place.

Below are the key code snippets.

Question: how to solve the problem of alternate loading of component content? I would like the availability of the remote component to be checked each time the website is accessed, not only when the main service is started.

Part:

```
(fetch("http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js"))
              ?'app2@http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js' //if available, load the remote version for the server
              :'./err/errors.js', //if not available, load the local version for the server
```

is to illustrate what I want to have.

app/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import loadable from '@loadable/component';


const Login_Register = loadable(() => import('app2/Login_Register'), {
  fallback: <div>loading content...</div>,
});

//Login_Register.load().then((ee)=>{console.log(ee.default() != null);});

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      gggg
        <Login_Register />
      fghfghfgh
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

moduleFederation.js:

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const { NodeFederationPlugin, StreamingTargetPlugin } = require('@module-federation/node');
const { FederationStatsPlugin } = require('@mf/loadable-adapters');
const FederationModuleIdPlugin = require("webpack-federation-module-id-plugin");

function lazyLoadRemoteClient(remoteUrl, appName) {
  return `promise new Promise(resolve => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = '${remoteUrl}'

  console.log('lazyLoadRemote', script.src);

  script.onload = () => {
    // the injected script has loaded and is available on window
    // we can now resolve this Promise
    const proxy = {
      get: (request) => window.${appName}.get(request),
      init: (arg) => {
        try {
          return window.${appName}.init(arg)
        } catch(e) {
          console.log('remote container already initialized', e)
        }
      }
    }
    resolve(proxy)
  }
  // inject this script with the src set to the versioned remoteEntry.js
  document.head.appendChild(script);
})`;
}

function lazyLoadRemoteServer(remoteUrl, appName) {
  return `promise new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('${remoteUrl}')
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        response;
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        resolve(resopnse.text());
      }).catch(function (error) {
        promise Promise.resolve().then(() =>  import('./../../error/errors.js').then(({ default: render }) => render))
      });
  }); `
}



module.exports = {
  client: [
    new FederationStatsPlugin(),
    new FederationModuleIdPlugin(),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        app2: (fetch("http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js"))
              ?'app2@http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js' //if available, load the remote version for the client
              :'./err/errors.js', //if not available, load the local version for the client
      },
    }),
  ],
  server: [
    new NodeFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      library: { type: 'commonjs-module' },
      //runtime: false,
      remotes: {
        app2: (fetch("http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js"))
              ?'app2@http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js' //if available, load the remote version for the server
              :'./err/errors.js', //if not available, load the local version for the server
      },
      shared: [
        {
          react: {
            requiredVersion: dependencies.react,
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
          },
          'react-dom': {
            requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom'],
            eager: false,
            singleton: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    new StreamingTargetPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      library: { type: 'commonjs-module' },
      remotes: {
        app2: (fetch("http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js"))
              ?'app2@http://localhost:3002/server/remoteEntry.js' //if available, load the remote version for the server
              :'./err/errors.js', //if not available, load the local version for the server
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```